# js function not returning onclick

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, jsfiddle

I've created a function that I can't get to return with onclick.

I'm sure it's something v simple i'm missing.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="schedule.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

     <input type="button" onclick="computeSchedule();" value="Submit" /><br>
     <p id="scheduleOutput"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function computeSchedule(loan_amount, interest_rate, payments_per_year, years, payment) {
var schedule = [];
var remaining = loan_amount;
var number_of_payments = payments_per_year * years;

for (var i=0; i<=number_of_payments; i++) {
    var interest = remaining * (interest_rate/100/payments_per_year);
    var principle = (payment-interest);
    var row = [i, principle>0?principle:0, interest>0?interest:0, remaining>0?remaining:0];
    schedule.push(row);
    remaining -= principle
}

return schedule;
}

var list = JSON.stringify(computeSchedule(100000, 0.005, 12, 15, 843.86), 0, 4)

document.getElementById('scheduleOutput').innerHTML = list;
```

I can get the function to automatically return in [jsFiddle onload](https://fiddle.jshell.net/a62a1ra0/2/), but when I change js settings to ["no wrap - in head"](https://fiddle.jshell.net/a62a1ra0/3/)it doesn't work. I assume whatever is happening there is also happening when I try to run outside of jsFiddle?

Comment: Try moving your `script` tag lines to the bottom of your HTML, just before the closing `body` tag.

Comment: When you're loading the `schedule.js` file, JavaScript code runs immediately, and at this point the HTML is not parsed as the DOM yet (which is why you get `undefined` as a result of `document.getElementById`).
Try moving the loading of `schedule.js` to the bottom of the `<body>` tag (right before `</body>`). This is exactly as choosing "no wrap, in <body>" in JS Fiddle.

Comment: yep that did it. thanks. Knew it would be simple for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sripts runs before body content is ready. That is why `document.getElementById` seems not to be working, because such element does not exist at this point of time.

Try to wrap your code in simple "content load" listener to be sure that it will be run after all elements are ready:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    function computeSchedule(loan_amount, interest_rate, payments_per_year, years, payment) {
        var schedule = [];
        var remaining = loan_amount;
        var number_of_payments = payments_per_year * years;

        for (var i=0; i<=number_of_payments; i++) {
            var interest = remaining * (interest_rate/100/payments_per_year);
            var principle = (payment-interest);
            var row = [i, principle>0?principle:0, interest>0?interest:0, remaining>0?remaining:0];
            schedule.push(row);
            remaining -= principle
        }

        return schedule;
    }

    var list = JSON.stringify(computeSchedule(100000, 0.005, 12, 15, 843.86), 0, 4)

    document.getElementById('scheduleOutput').innerHTML = list;
});
```

And yes, your *onclick* is now passing no data to the function. So, you also need to pass params to it and everything should work fine.

Comment: Yes that works, however I'm trying to go one step further and use variables in the function. Essentially what I'm trying to create is a mortgage calculator where a user enters loan amount(100000), rate (0.005), years(15). I then calc the monthly payment (843.86) from another function and return this to html. Any ideas how I could run the computeSchedule function on button click after previous functions have been run? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you're click on the button the function computeSchedule() is firing, but no values are being passed to it. I'm will to bet if you put value in the parameter on the html line it would work.

```
<input type="button" onclick="computeSchedule(100000, 0.005, 12, 15, 843.86);" value="Submit" />
```